# Serilog- how to use UTC date in file name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I want to create my log file name with UTC date-time. I have used the below configuration in my appsettings.json file. I have used rollingInterval=Hour which is always giving me my local hour in the file name.

```
 "Serilog": {
    "Using": [],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Logs\\log.txt",
          "outputTemplate": "{UtcTimestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} {Message}{NewLine:1}{Exception:1}",
          "rollingInterval": "Hour",
          "shared": true
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Logs\\log.json",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog",
          "rollingInterval": "Hour",
          "shared": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I have also created UtcTimestampEnricher to get UTC time in every request which is working fine.

Comment: Maybe you can refer to [this](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/issues/56),and you can see the [link](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.File/Sinks/File/Clock.cs) dmch-dev offered.He says it uses `DateTime.Now` rather than  `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?